# Changing Background Image on Change in Device Width

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a full screen background image. The problem that I face is that it gets chopped when viewing the website from a mobile handset.

What I would Like to have is the focus object getting viewed in mobile. So i have a cropped image with mobile dimensions of the focus object. I would like my code to detect a mobile device and change the `background:url();` to the normal image if the device is tablet or desktop but the cropped version of image if a smartphone is being used. I am unaware how this might take place. I know **JQuery** and **@media** rules will help me.

Comment: *"I know JQuery and @media rules will help me."* - Probably even just `@media`. But if you know this, why do you ask?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/jonom/jquery-focuspoint can help you?

Comment: @GolezTrol I know what I could use. I dont know HOW to use it. Sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the media object you check if the current screen size is bigger than 768. If it is the #bg values will be overwritten.

```
#bg {
  background-image: url('small.jpg');
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #bg {
    background-image: url('big.jpg');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :') I didnt think of this. I always thought it would require JQuery ( Which I am not familiar with) This HAS to be the easiest technique.